# Ribbon With Eureka in Spring Boot

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I want to know about the flow of working on Eureka and Ribbon together.

a) When ribbon is used without eureka, it keeps serverList. But while using eureka,it fetches the serverList from Eureka. But when does ribbon fetches this data? on start-up or on every request or on after some regular interval?

b) what happens when a service instance is added? how does ribbon gets yo know about it.

c) How does Eureka Server keeps tracks of instances. Does instances send heartbeat or does Eureka Poll them?.

d) How does Eureka know when one instance of service dies.?

e) How does ribbon keeps tracks of instances.?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to most of these cases.
1.Ribbon has refresh interval like 30 sec ,when it fecthed the list of instances from consul or eureka.3.Ribbon uses Iping to fetch instaces.